# Security Token from ADFS Identical?

Tags: office365, adfs

For a given user, does he require different security token from ADFS to access different Claims-Based-Applications?

That means, if user authenticates to App1 through ADFS by getting token T1, can App1 query App2 while posing as the user by using T1?

Or does T2 needs to be regenerated from ADFS?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 3.0 (Server 2012 R2)? You've tagged "iis" which is not used by ADFS 3.0.

In the passive scenario (browser) - no.

The claims rules for both applications may be different. Also the token has fields like "audience_uri" which won't match both RP.

Why do you want this?

User authenticates to T1 - gets T1 token. Now user wants to authenticate to T2. ADFS sees that they are already authenticated so seamlessly issues T2 token i.e. they will not have to authenticate again.

If you want "user_impersonation" you need to look at active (WCF) or web API (OAuth).

Comment: IIS was a tag for another post, thanks for spotting. I've removed it now.

Yes, my App1 needs to do impersonation to query App2. Can you share more on how active (WCF) or web API (OAuth) can handle this? App2 is actually Sharepoint Online, in external web, so it can only have SSO authentication by a security token from ADFS.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to impersonate? If SP is correctly federated against ADFS, then auth to T1 and you will get seamlessly logged into SP when you navigate to T2.